# How to encode database file from unix ansi to unix utf-8

Tags: database, unix

[file program .exe the result of database fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kXiW.png)I think the problem of long term storage files change utf 8 to ansi I can in .txt but database files is difficult I dont know how to do it.

It can open by excel readonly but codecs changed

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add more details and an actual question. Show the type of database, the database schema and settings, maybe the code of the corresponding application, and explain what exactly you want to change. Please also specify what exactly you mean with "unix ansi".

Comment: .dbf files I think header of file would be repair

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Unfortunately the information you provided is not sufficient to help you. You didn't answer most of my questions. What program do you use? Where does the database come from? why do you think it is an encoding problem? Can you open the database with a generic program?